# Is it recommended to put a max TTL in every key even if it has no TTL for server-side caching?

Tags: redis

[Redis server-assisted client side caching](https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching) official page says:

> Putting a max TTL in every key is a good idea, even if it had no TTL. This is a good protection against bugs or connection issues that would make the client having old data in the local copy.

...but Redis documentation does not say whether it is a good practice to always set at least a max TTL for server-side caching.

---

Is it a bad practice to do not set a TTL at all?

For example, I cache some data for a long time and I am fine to set `expire=None` for it because the data changes rarely.

At the same time, I am afraid that I will do some code changes and I will forget to clean up absolute key/value. As I understand, that absolute data may stay forever in Redis only wasting space.

Is it a good practice to always set at least a huge TTL (e.g. 1 year) to stay safe?

Comment: You might want to look at setting max memory and an eviction policy as another way of accomplishing the same thing. https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: @GuyRoyse Setting max memory + eviction policy will not work well for my case because I need to cache (expensive to recalculate) data under high load (that may occur periodically). We scale up memory under high load.